# MSSQL Convert VARCHAR to Currency

Tags: sql-server

very new to casting VARCHAR to currencies. Please i do need guidance here.

Please Is this how to go about casting to currency as i apparently have some form of confusion on here.

Query looks like this

```
select credit, debit, balance , 'GBP' + CONVERT (varchar 50) cast (credit as money),1, (debit as money),1, (balance as money),1 as [debit], [credit], [balance] from transactions
```

**Edit**

As Requested, I paste ma table Columns for you to see

```
    TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  NUMERIC_PRECISION   NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX NUMERIC_SCALE   DATETIME_PRECISION  CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG   CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA    CHARACTER_SET_NAME  COLLATION_CATALOG   COLLATION_SCHEMA    COLLATION_NAME  DOMAIN_CATALOG  DOMAIN_SCHEMA   DOMAIN_NAME
banksql dbo transactions    id  1   NULL    NO  int NULL    NULL    10  10  0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    depositor_name  2   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    accountNo1  3   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    telephone   4   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    transaction_desc    5   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    credit  6   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    debit   7   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    balance 8   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
banksql dbo transactions    transaction_date    9   NULL    YES varchar 50  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    iso_1   NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the table schema? It would help others to know the column types.

Comment: @NisargShah i have updated. You can see it now..

Comment: Man, I hope my bank doesn't store my balance as a `varchar`. That schema is terrible.

Comment: @Tim Yup, you should not store balance as a `varchar`. There is a reason why different data types are supported. Proper datatypes generally optimize the disk space required and the cost of numerical operations.

Comment: @RacilHilan , calm down.. assistance here..

Comment: Assistance in what? Committing suicide? That schema is suicidal :)

Comment: do i change to Decimal or ? started to think it would affect information on report viewer.

Comment: Yes, I personally would use `decimal`. But you can use `money` or `smallmoney` if you like.

Comment: @Tim There are two types `money` and `smallmoney` IIRC. IMO you should read more about the datatypes, before going ahead with this.

Comment: Thanks So Much. All problems has been Resolved and its working fine now.  Thanks folks

Comment: As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!), please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*. But - in order to close this question - it would be fine either to place your own solution and accpet it, or to accept and vote any existing answer you consider best. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You were told already about the really bad idea to store numeric values as strings... So I won't talk about this. Just some hints about type conversion:

This part of your code means nothing:

```
'GBP' + CONVERT (varchar 50) cast (credit as money),1, (debit as money),1, (balance as money),1 as [debit]
```

You can change the type of a value either with `CAST()` or with `CONVERT()`

- `SELECT CAST('123' AS INT)`  returns the **number** 123
- `SELECT CONVERT(INT, '123')` does exactly the same

From version SQL Server 2012+ there is `TRY_CAST()` and `TRY_CONVERT()` for a better handling of invalid values too.

- `CAST()` will use the implicit type conversion, while
- `CONVERT()` allows for a third parameter to specify the conversion's mode. [Find the details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT 'GBP' + credit         AS ConcatenatedString --as your "credit" is a string type already...
      ,CAST(credit AS MONEY)  AS CastedString       --numeric return
FROM transactions
```